# Removing Unwanted Characters

Tags: c#, regex, casing

I am trying to scrub a list of items using another list and it's working fine except for its not ignoring case.  When I try to add ordinal or regex casing checks, I get a syntax error.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Here is my code:

```
List<string> removeChars = new List<string>(textBox_ScrubList.Text.Split(','));
            for (int i = 0; i < sortBox1.Count; i++)
                foreach (string repl in removeChars)
                    sortBox1[i] = sortBox1[i].Replace(repl, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And here is the syntax error I am getting:

[image: Regex Casing Syntax Error]

Comment: It's just the original list that I am scrubbing.

Comment: A `List<String>` or something else? And what's the exact error message? I've made an educated guess at an answer based on the partial information, but please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list as well.

Comment: You should answer your own question if you figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.  The last line:

```
 sortBox1[i] = sortBox1[i].Replace(repl, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

had to be changed to:

```
 sortBox1[i] = Regex.Replace(sortBox1[i], repl, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sortBox1` is a `List<string>` or similar, the problem is that [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) doesn't have any overload which takes a `RegexOptions`.

You can use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx), but in that case you should probably be able to construct a *single* regular expression to remove all the characters in one go. If you *do* want to remove them one at a time, you may want to use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to avoid regular expression patterns from being a problem. (For example, if it tried to replace "." with "", you'd end up getting rid of everything.)